# check if the id of a resource is in the id list of another resource displayed in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a resource

```
$scope.list = [
             { listId:1, name: "Test1" }, 
             { listId:2, name: "Test 2" }
              ];
```

I also have an another resource referencing the first one with `listId`

```
$scope.includedList = [
           {
             includedListId:1, 
             title: "Title 1",
             listId:1 
           }];
```

and I have a display with repeat and i want to check if the list item is included in the second resource.

```
< a ng-repeat="item in list" 
    ng-class="selected if item is included in includedList"
>
```

Comment: In `$scope.list` are you sure you have 2 different item types? `id` and `listId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function

```
$scope.isIncluded = function ()
```

and then

> < a ng-repeat="item in list" ng-class="{selected:isIncluded(item, includedList)}">

I don't understand the exact logic of the inclusion so i leave the function empty

Comment: i am trying to write something like this, i wondering if there is more "anular" way to do it.